# Recursive function in python to find the sum of digits of number

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I want to use a recursive algorithm for the function, which should print out the sum of all the digits of a given number.

Here is my code. For example, sum_of_digits(343) will return an output of 10.

```
numbers = [1, 2]
def sum_of_digits(n):
    for n in

sum_of_digits(343)
```

The output I'm trying to achieve: 10

Comment: Recursive algorithm is overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to use recursion, one method would be to get the individual digits by modding `n` with `10` and adding that to the sum of the remaining digits (computed by `sum_of_digits(n // 10)`:

```
def sum_of_digits(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    return (n % 10) + sum_of_digits(n // 10)

print(sum_of_digits(343))
```

Output:

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_of_digits(n):
    result = 0
    for x in str(n):
        result += int(x)
    return result

sum_of_digits(343) # 10
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this simplest solution:

```
number = 343

sum_of_digits = sum(map(int, str(number)))
print(sum_of_digits)
10
```